# How to install Ubuntu on H: Drive?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows, dual-boot

Apologies if this question already exist.

How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on H: Drive? I had boot Ubuntu 12.04 from USB and when I click on something else when installing Ubuntu it shows some drives like dev/sd1.

In Windows XP I have my H: drive ready to be installed with Ubuntu. But I don't know which dev/sdXX is h: drive.

Comment: go back into windows and find out the size of the hdd or partition. then go back to installing ubuntu, then just find the drive or partition with that amount of space that matches your linux H: drive. it might be easier to reformat the H: and give the drive or partition a name so you can find it easier.

Comment: my drive is 20.7 gb used 118 mb

Comment: ummm... what? your whole H: drive is 20.7GB? are you able to reformat it? if so. you can just go back to the installing of ubuntu and find that 20.7GB drive or very close to it. and use that drive to install ubuntu on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows XP, go to Start...Run and type `diskmgmt.msc`. That will open up Disk Management and give you a graphical view of where Drive H lies on your disk.

Now start the Ubuntu LiveCD/USB l, and run `gparted`. You will get a view that is similar to what you got in Disk Management. Find the part where drive H was, and note its `/dev/sdx` label. That's the one you want!

Comment: my drive name is /dev/sdb7 so when i click install now this message appear:
No root filesystem is defined please correct this form the parturitig menu

Comment: My H: Drive is gone after after installing ubuntu 12.04 inside windows? when i installed ubuntu 12.04 from usb inside windows in drive H: ( dev/sdv7) when installation is finished it say restart when i restart i shows no option to boot ubuntu or windows? when it automatically boot windows my H: drives is also gone now how can i make duel boot choose wheater boot ubuntu or windows it's shows nothing when installation is finished and when i restarted my pc

Comment: @LiangLee You need to use your BIOS to select to boot from that drive.