# No boot option after installing ubuntu 12.04 inside windows xp and drive h: is also gone

Tags: installation

My H: Drive is gone.  After after installing Ubuntu 12.04 inside windows.  When I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from USB inside windows in drive H: ( dev/sdv7) when the installation finished it said to restart, when I restarted I did not see an option to boot Ubuntu or windows.  When it automatically booted into windows my H: drives is also gone.  Now how can I dual boot to choose whether to boot Ubuntu or Windows.  It shows nothing when the installation is finished and when I restarted my pc.

Comment: i have already installed xp so i have insalled ubuntu through usb

Comment: Mitch wanted to say what option did u choose while installing? is installing along side windows or something else

Comment: along side of windows

Comment: Can you supply partitioning information?

Comment: i used ext2 format file system

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148362/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-h-drive - it helps if you linked to your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Boot loader. Try boot-repair. More info about the app here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair